# Trying to deploy a small app that makes changes to the registry

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, registry

I have the following program and when I build it (Release config). It runs on my developer machine as an administrator. However when I run it on an End User (non admin), It crashes and says something about Security. Is there anything I need to do in the properties (or in code) so it can masquerade as an Administrator

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Win32;

namespace LotusTrustedSites
{       
    class ReportDownloader    
    {        
        [STAThread]        
        static void Main(string[] args)        
        {            
            const string domainsKeyLocation = @"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap\Domains";            
            const string domain = @"newsite.com";            
            const int trustedSiteZone = 0x2;            
            var subdomains = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {                                     
                    {"www", "https"},                                     
                    {"www", "http"},                                     
                    {"blog", "https"},                                     
                    {"blog", "http"}                                 
                };            
            RegistryKey currentUserKey = Registry.CurrentUser;            
            currentUserKey.GetOrCreateSubKey(domainsKeyLocation, domain, false);            
            foreach (var subdomain in subdomains)            
            {                
                CreateSubdomainKeyAndValue(currentUserKey, domainsKeyLocation, domain, subdomain, trustedSiteZone);            
            }            //automation code        
        }        

        private static void CreateSubdomainKeyAndValue(RegistryKey currentUserKey, string domainsKeyLocation, string domain, KeyValuePair<string, string> subdomain, int zone)        
        {            
            RegistryKey subdomainRegistryKey = currentUserKey.GetOrCreateSubKey(string.Format(@"{0}\{1}", domainsKeyLocation, domain), subdomain.Key, true);            
            object objSubDomainValue = subdomainRegistryKey.GetValue(subdomain.Value);            
            if (objSubDomainValue == null || Convert.ToInt32(objSubDomainValue) != zone)            
            {                
                subdomainRegistryKey.SetValue(subdomain.Value, zone, RegistryValueKind.DWord);            
            }        
        }    
    }    
    public static class RegistryKeyExtensionMethods    
    {        
        public static RegistryKey GetOrCreateSubKey(this RegistryKey registryKey, string parentKeyLocation, string key, bool writable)        
        {            
            string keyLocation = string.Format(@"{0}\{1}", parentKeyLocation, key);           
            RegistryKey foundRegistryKey = registryKey.OpenSubKey(keyLocation, writable);            
            return foundRegistryKey ?? registryKey.CreateSubKey(parentKeyLocation, key);        
        }        
        public static RegistryKey CreateSubKey(this RegistryKey registryKey, string parentKeyLocation, string key)        
        {            
            RegistryKey parentKey = registryKey.OpenSubKey(parentKeyLocation, true); //must be writable == true            
            if (parentKey == null) 
            { 
                throw new NullReferenceException(string.Format("Missing parent key: {0}", parentKeyLocation)); 
            }            
            RegistryKey createdKey = parentKey.CreateSubKey(key);            
            if (createdKey == null) 
            { 
                throw new Exception(string.Format("Key not created: {0}", key)); 
            }            
            return createdKey;        
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: If you don't mind my asking, what exactly are you trying to do?  `Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap\Domains` doesn't seem like a place where your software ought to be creating anything.  The first thing you should ask yourself if an operation doesn't work under non-admin settings is whether you should really be doing what you're doing, or whether you should be doing it in some other way, such as with application settings in a .config file.

Answer (score 2):

Writing to the registry is a privileged operation - you need to have the right permissions.

The account that the application is running under needs to have appropriate permissions.

Answer (score -1):

Creating registry settings programmaticaly is a bit of the wrong thing to do. The problem with it is that the Windows installer sub-system cannot track those entries, and repair them, or remove them as needed. The better choice is to use an application settings file, or to provide a MSI installer that creates those entries for you.

Comment: I work in a large enterprise and sometimes we need to install apps via Server. However sometimes it doesn't install so we need to manually install it then configure it. I'd rather right a small app that makes the necessary changes to the registry and get it done in 1 click.

Comment: @Cocoa - Which is probably part of the reason why every enterprise machine I've had ran 10x slower than a similarly unencombered machine. In this case, its not that big a deal, but it is a bad habit that causes problems that can be migitated by using the windows installer mechanism.

Comment: @Cocoa - And its not a wrong answer. It's a quite correct one.